# What would be an appropriate in case of multiple moderators forward or backward regression

Tags: regression, interaction

I am trying to test a model using hierarchical regression analysis. I have one predictor, one outcome and five moderators. My main question is should I put the moderators in the model using forward regression or backward regression so basically:

Option 1: 
Block 1: co-variables (method Enter). 
Block 2: predictor (method Enter)
Block 3: predictor + 5 main effects (method Enter). 
Block 4: 5 interaction terms (so centralized main effect x predictor) (method **Forward**)

Option 2: 
Option 1: 
block 1: co-variables (method Enter). 
Block 2: predictor (method Enter)
Block 3: predictor + 5 main effects (method Enter). 
Block 4: 5 interaction terms (so centralized main effect x predictor) (method **Backward**)

I tried both ways and they lead to different findings. With option 1 I do find some moderating effects. With option 2, there are no moderating effects. I know there is literature on forward and backward regression but with this many moderators in one model I am lost...

Answer (score 0):

Forward and backward model selection do not result in the same model. "Successful" entry of covariates in a stepwise model does not mean that they are moderating effects. Not surprisingly, the forward model tends to pick fewer variables, but this is not always the case as in your example.

Read the documentation for your software. Be sure the significance level for *entering the model* is the same as the significance level for *staying in the model*.

The main issue is that a "moderating effect" is a *causal* designation, and stepwise model selection is a *predictive* procedure, so I wouldn't trust the findings from either model. Rather, fit one or more confirmatory models according to the direct acyclic graph (DAG) that describes the proposed causal mechanism, and describe the inference accordingly.